What reasons have Elon Musk given for entering politics?
What reasons have Elon Musk publicly given for his decision to get involved with politics?

Money, power, influence, adoration. We cannot delve into the mind of Elon as to the specific "why".

Unless he tells us (and in which case you'd have to take his claims with a grain of salt)...

This question asks for publicly available reasons, so any answer answering the question would have to be able to be "verified with sources available to the public". Please reopen

Don't reopen.  This is a a rubbish question.  The "publically available" reason is the same as literally every single other person that enters politics:  to influence policy.  There's no other answer possible and the same answer would work for Trump, Harris, Biden, Obama, Reagan, Washington, Caesar ...

Edited to be more definitively answerable.  Ask @JamesK points out, "the reason" in the general sense is the same for many people (gaining power for its own sake would be the other big one I'd cite).  But the answer already here shows that Musk has given his own reasons (or at least his public ones), and asking about those is valid and answerable.

This question is on-topic, but it shows no research effort.

TL;DR Woke-mind virus and free speech (per Musk)
According to Musk, "unless the woke-mind virus, which is fundamentally antiscience, antimerit, and antihuman in general, is stopped, civilization will never become multiplanetary". For someone who has dedicated much of their life to making civilization multiplanetary, a threat to that goal is something you would take seriously, and try to stop.
Jared Birchall, the manager of Musk's personal office also thinks that Musk "lost a son who changed first and last names and won't speak to him anymore because of this woke-mind virus" and that Musk "is a firsthand witness on a very personal level of the damaging effect of being indoctrinated by this woke-mind religion".
He has also said that "At its heart wokeness is divisive, exclusionary, and hateful. It gives mean people a shield to be mean and cruel, armed with a false virtue" and that "woke-mind virus resides primarily in the Democratic Party."
Later, he would say "In the past, I voted Democrat, because they were (mostly) the kindness party" "But they have become the party of division & hate, so I can no longer support them and will vote Republican. Now, watch their dirty tricks campaign against me unfold."
Free speech also seems to be related. Musk would later purchase Twitter over concerns about censorship. Before that though, after announcing he would vote Republican, he said "The attacks against me should be viewed through a political lens--this is their standard (despicable) playbook--but nothing will deter me from fighting for a good future and your right to free speech."
(This is all sourced from Walter Isaacson's biography of Elon Musk)

Apparently democracy would have been "finished" if Biden were re-elected, according to Musk anyway.

He he, maybe cite something instead of a link only answer?  Sheesh, I just got through calling out the other guy/gal (that gender neutral enough?) for proselytizing now I have a cat to herd in the other direction ;-)
